# SQL (JOIN) - two result from one column to two column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT a.cp_node_id,
       a.cmi_node_id,
       a.user_id,
       a.learner_name,
       a.completion_status,
       a.success_status,
       b.id title,
       c.dep,
       d.field_id,
       d.value
       FROM cmi_node a
JOIN cmi_objective b
  ON a.cmi_node_id=b.cmi_node_id
 AND a.completion_status = 'completed'
 AND a.success_status = 'passed'
 AND a.cp_node_id = '1'
JOIN usr_data c
  ON a.user_id = c.usr_id
JOIN udf_text d
  ON a.user_id = d.usr_id
GROUP BY a.cmi_node_id
```

In my "D" table I have one column, there is two result, example:

```
ID: field_id:  value:
1   1          test
1   2          text2
2   1          test
2   2          text3
3   1          test2
3   2          text6
etc...
```

In field_in always are 1 or 2.

I need print ALL my users from "cmi_node", example:

```
user_id  learner_name
1        George
2        Michel
3        James
```

And I want to add two column from "D" table:
example:

```
user_id  learner_name  field_in_first field_in_second value_first value_second
1        George        1              2               test        text2
2        Michel        1              2               test        text3
3        James         1              2               test2       text6
```

Thank you

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: its mysql............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the same table two times.

```
JOIN udf_text d1 ON a.user_id = d.usr_id AND field_id = 1
JOIN udf_text d2 ON a.user_id = d.usr_id AND field_id = 2
```

then you can access d1.field_id, d2.field_id, d1.value and d2.value

Comment: I can't, my reputation is less then 15, sorry.
Thanks again!